# Use Taleo to Authenticate a Username and Password

Tags: taleo

I want to create a custom login on an external site that will just use Taleo to authenticate the username and password (meaning, literally, just check if that user exists). Is there a good way of doing this? I'm having trouble finding the answer in Taleo's API methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using my library : https://github.com/Polzme/Taleo

Don't hesitate to ask for help.

Comment: Can you provide an example? How would you authenticate a username and password with the linked library?

Comment: Hi, the library is no more maintained and i'm sorry but I do not remember how to do that. I do remember it was quite easy, I guess if you look through the code you will find what you're looking for.